# How do you use git from WSL in RubyMine?

Tags: git, rubymine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm experimenting with the new Windows Subsystem for Linux as a way to develop Rails applications in Windows. I have WSL installed and I have git in it but how do I use that git from a Windows GUI application, specifically, RubyMine:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have WSL installed and I have git in it but how do I use that git from a Windows GUI application, specifically, RubyMine

You don't: from a Windows GUI application, you use [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (Portable edition) that you can unzip anywhere you want.

Your Git in the [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq) can access any file that your Git in Windows can, through `/mnt/C`.
Both Gits can co-exist and manage the same Git repo.

Comment: I'd still need to access WSL binaries from Windows though. I'll make another question.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495626/how-do-i-access-linux-binaries-from-windows-when-using-wsl

Comment: I tried to set up my WSL by setting the path to the linux git `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\git`, however rubymine is expecting a windows executable therefore is not possible atm. The portable trick should work for now.

Comment: @zetacu I suppose you are using WSL2 (I had written that answer at the time of WSL1).